# Create a timezone dropdown with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, timezone

Are there any Ember.js addons that would make it easy to create a timezone dropdown? I'm thinking about a `Ember.TimezoneSelect` view for example.

If not, then how should I go about doing it myself?

One way would be to just have the timezone array in `App`: `App.timezones = [...]`. And then in the view: `{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="App.timezones"}}`. Is there a better solution?

Or should I create a TimezoneController, bind the Select to one of its property, so that I could later just do an ajax request to get all the timezones, and it would update the select field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about IANA/Olson time zones [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), then I would recommend against a drop-down list.  There are so many, it can be overwhelming to a user.  Picking the right one can be challenging.  Map-based timezone pickers provide a much better user experience.  [Here is one in Javascript that I use a lot.](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker)  See [here](http://scratch.andrewl.in/timezone-picker/example_site/gmaps_example.html) for a live demo.

If you're talking about Windows time zones, then yes - you could just return the list from `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` using the `Id` as the key of the dropdown, and the `DisplayName` as the value.

I don't think you'll find anything specific to Ember in this regard, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it

```
TimeZoneComponent = Ember.Select.extend

  content: [...]
```

Extend the Em.Select view, passing a fixed set of options!

https://gist.github.com/etozzato/ec6fdb6114a59dd04819

Enjoy EmberJS ;)